# What are some good resources for genetic algorithm pathing that aren't JUST shortest distance?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, path-finding, traveling-salesman, threat-model

I am looking to develop a pathing agent that determines best path based on both shortest distance AND threat avoidance. I have found an abundance of resources that help with shortest distance optimization, but haven't found nearly as much on adding a threat avoidance (or any other parameter) to the optimization decision.

I am curious what resources you all know of that could help with intelligent decision making in this regime. Thanks.